# Librosa load many MP3 memory usage

Tags: python, memory, mp3, audio-processing, librosa

I want to load about 25K mp3 audio files in a loop and process them in a Jupyter Notebook. When loading these audio files my RAM usages keeps growing when this should not be the case. When examining the variables in RAM the audio files do not show up and even a `%reset -f` does not free up the memory. The example below will make the RAM usage grow indefinitely, which should not be the case as the result of function `process_audio_file` is just 2 bytes.

My question is, how do I process these 25K audio files without the RAM usage growing?

```
def process_audio_file(fname):
    librosa.core.load(fname, sr=None)
    return 42

res = np.ndarray(shape=len(file_names), dtype=np.int16)
# Loop will make RAM usage grow till 16GB, causing an out of memory error
for idx, fname in enumerate(file_names):
    res[idx] = process_audio_file(fname)
```

Comment: try to use a memory profiler to figure out where the memory is leaked? Note that they might have limited visibility into C level objects.

Comment: one thing to check could be whether it happens with WAV files also

Comment: and if you can provide a reproducible example I would encourage to post this a a bugreport in librosa, as it very much sounds like a bug